# Creating Liquibase DataBaseChangelog manually for my JPA entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I am new to `Liquibase` and I want to use it to create initial `ddl` scripts for my `JPA entites`. For that I need to create the `databaseChangeLog` so as to run the profile `liquibase:updateSQL` and to generate the scripts.

How can I get the metadata from my JPA entities and how can I use it to create the `databaseChangeLog` manually ? Is there any Git link ?

I don't have a physical db so I am not looking at the mechanism to regenerate the `change-set` from the db.

I am ok in providing the `liquibase` properties with information about `driver`,`dialect` etc.

Comment: See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app), section #8 specifically

Comment: #8 , No 8 i guess

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant #6, don't know where the '8' came from :P

Comment: Isn't that to find the difference between db and jpa entities ? I tried something like that and I had an different expectation . check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455584/liquibasediff-not-giving-me-expected-result

Comment: OK, I guess I misread your question. I don't think it is possible without having a database to compare your entities against. You will need an empty db

Comment: I tried that , but create script is not coming as the difference. Don't know if it is the mistake in my code. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55455584/4229716 please check here