# liquibase:diff not giving me expected result

Tags: spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I have a `JPA entity` called customer and goes like this

```
@Entity
public class Customer {



private int custNo;
private String custName;
private String country;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(int custNumber, String custName, String country) {
    this.custNo = custNumber;
    this.custName = custName;
    this.country = country;
}

public int getCustNo() {
   return custNo;
}

public void setCustNo(int custNo) {
   this.custNo = custNo;
}

public String getCustName() {
   return custName;
}

public void setCustName(String custName) {
   this.custName = custName;
}

public String getCountry() {
   return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
   this.country = country;
}
}
```

and my db has 2 tables :- BE132_name and BE1jj231_address ,

I am running my profile `liquibase:diff` and is giving me the change set as follows

```
    <changeSet author="jobs (generated)" id="1554122585461-10">
    <dropTable tableName="BE132_name"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="jobs (generated)" id="1554122585461-11">
    <dropTable tableName="BE1jj231_address"/>
    </changeSet>
```

As you can see it created drop table since I dont have its corresponding `JPA` entities. But why is it not creating the `create script` for my Customer ?

For an empty data base (one without any tables) , I am getting

```
 INFO 4/2/19 5:47 PM: liquibase: No changes found, nothing to do
```

Comment: Is it because the table is not already existing the db ? can someone help me out here.

Answer (score -1):

I used the `liquibase-hibernate plugin` for this!. It is capable of generating the `changeset` for a JPA entity even if its corresponding table is not there in the db.

The plugin

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <configuration>                  
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration> 
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>               
    </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

and the `liquibase.properties`

```
changeLogFile=classpath:liquibase-changeLog.xml
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oauth_reddit
username=tutorialuser
password=tutorialmy5ql
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:org.baeldung.persistence.model
  ?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog.xml
```

The `referenceUrl` is using package scan, so the dialect parameter is required. `changeLogFile` is the location of changeset for which the db is in sync. `diffChangeLogFile` is the location where the difference changelog has to be flushed.